# typo3 append frame_class to layouts

Tags: typo3, rendering, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I want to adjust my rendering of layout and frame elements in the frontend.

I have different layouts defined via typoscript. Now I want to define two frames, that should adjust the wrapped elements on layout level.

Currently the two layers (layout and frame) gets rendered like the following:
(exact classes might differ)

```
<div class="layout-class">
  <div class="frame-class">
    <p>This is Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change that behaviour via Typoscript to render it like the following:

```
<div class="layout-class frame-class">
 <p>This is Content</p>
</div>
```

Is there a possibility to do so?
I tried the following:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = TEXT
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    field = frame_class
    required = 1
    noTrimWrap = |field:frame_class-| |
}
```

Comment: You could use a `COA`instead of the `TEXT`-cObject and within the `COA`a `TEXT`-Object for each field. Or you can use [`insertData`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#insertdata).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying this: ```tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default = COA
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default {
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        noTrimWrap = | {field:frame_class}-| |
        insertData = 1
    }
}``` without success yet

Comment: `class="frame-frameClass frame-layout-layoutClass"` is already the default with fluid_styled_content: https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html#L6 - do you use css_styled_content still?

Comment: You are working with TYPO3 v9, correct? And you are using fluid_styled_content, correct? If this is true, there seems to be something wrong with your site package because what you try to achieve is the default behaviour.

Comment: I see what you mean. We just upgraded to Typo3 9 and it seems that we are currently using fluid and css styled content, were our layout is still css styled but the frames are fluid styled.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = COA
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = layout_class
    20 = TEXT
    20.field = frame_class
    20.wrap = -|
}
```

### Solution 2:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = TEXT
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    value = {field:layout_class}-{field:frame_class}
    stdWrap.insertData = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Deactivate `css_styled_content`
- Activate `fluid_styled_content`
- Adjust your project's stylesheet to `fluid_styled_content` classes